# IISExpress 8 Cannot read configuration file redirection.config

Tags: iis-express

I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64) with IISExpress8 and when navigating to

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>iisexpress.exe
```

it says:

Filename: redirection.config

> Error: Cannot read configuration file

Any ideas where to start? 
I can't find anything...

Comment: I found this question while traying to resolve an issue with Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015. My fix was: my user could not write to my personal folder (I'm in Administrators group and I'm the folder owner), so I went to security configurations and give myself full access. Restarted VS 2015 and voi-la =)

Answer (score 66):

I had a similar issue to @Myles J but renaming `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` didn't work. What I had to do was the following:

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Rename the `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config` **directory**.
3. Start Visual Studio again. The `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config` directory will be recreated with the default config files.
4. Copy the original `applicationhost.config` file over the autogenerated one.

Before anyone asks: the permissions on the folders were identical, the read-only flag was not set on the folder or its files, and I didn't modify `applicationhost.config` in any way.

Comment: For future devs -- this didn't work for me until after I had uninstalled/reinstalled IIS Express. I renamed the folder, launched VS, didn't work.  Reinstalled IIS Express, launched VS, got the error. Stopped VS, renamed the folder, restarted. No error. (VS2013, IISExpress 8.0)

Comment: I had my documents stored in OneDrive, and the /IISExpress folder was marked "online only". So the shadow file was there, but Visual Studio couldn't read it. Right Click the IISExpress Folder, and select "Make Available Offline" or as other mention (i didn't try this) maybe delete the folder. Then everything worked!

Comment: Exactly the same situation as @ScottCate
Made the \Documents\IISExpress folder available offline. Renamed the config folder to config.backup and restarted Visual Studio (2015 RC).. that fixed it.

Comment: Similar to @ScottCate and Shailen_Sukul, - right-click and selected **Make Available Offline**  - didn't even bother to make a backup copy of config directory - but, maybe a good idea - restarted Visual Studio

Comment: I dont have this folder %userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\

Comment: In my case, I tried to reload the project couple times, didn't work. Tried to close the visual studio and re-opened, didn't work. Checked on internet. Came to this page. Just thought to give another go by clicking on 'Reload project'. And it worked. Just like that !

Comment: This works for me every time when I accidentally replace my local applicationhost.config with the one that has somehow got checked into source control

Comment: Another OneDrive victime is here. I authenticated to me onedrive account and then the problem resolved. Finally I removed the OneDrive for peace.

Answer (score 61):

After installing IIS Express, copy all files from

> C:\Program Files\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer

to

> %userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config

Comment: This did it for me, +1.

Comment: It's stuff like this that makes working with VS and dotnet = working hard. Not working smart. Thank you.

Comment: I found that files inside %userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config was missing for me, suddenly i day i started facing this issue, may be some corporate cleanup did clear files for me. I did as mentioned an error is gone, Thanks alot for fix

Answer (score 32):

Right click on your project file and Edit the project file and remove the URL from IISUrl and reload your project then it will work

Comment: Why aren't there more upvotes for this? This is the easiest (and also the correct) solution offered. +1.

Comment: I also had to clear out the IISAppRootUrl item from the project, but a nice simple solution

Comment: Messing with the IIS Express config directory and files did not work. This solution (editing the project file) worked perfectly. Thank you Deva.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer.  I deleted the value (just leaving <IisUrl></IisUrl>) and my build succeeded.  I agree that more people should have upvoted this.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I removed the value under IISUrl, and tried to reload. Didn't work. The removed the IISUrl tag, tried to reload.. didn't work. I removed the DevelopmentServerPort tag, tried to reload.. didn't work. Tried removing the parent tags, and finally removed the project extensions tag. NONE of them worked! Terrible.. It randomly worked if I disabled Resharper on VS startup. I  had to enable Resharper (to work with unit tests), and I needed to restart VS again for Resharper to work. Then I get the SAME PROBLEM!!

Comment: I've tried clearing the URL from the IISUrl tag, but it didn't work. I also tried deleting the IISUrl tag, but that too didn't work. I'm using VS 2022 with a ASP.NET 2.0 solution, on a Windows 10 Enterprise machine.

Answer (score 12):

I have just resolved this.  It is a strange solution but it worked for me.  Here are the steps I took:

Navigate to the folder containing the local IISExpress config files (normally My Documents>IISExpress>config on Windows7).

Find the applicationhost.config file.  Rename it to something different e.g. applicationhost2.config.

Navigate to your web project in Visual Studio (I was using VS 2012).  Right click on the web project and select Use IISExpress.  Run the project.  It should fail due to the renaming of the config file.

Change the name of the configuration file back to application.config.  Ensure "Use Local IIS Web Server" is selected in the web project settings.  Run the solution.

This worked for me.

Comment: @Myles J - in my case, after renaming applicationhost.config, VS2015 just recreated it when I loaded the solution. However, although I can now load my solution and projects, it will NOT run. it builds fine, but I get the `System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'myApp.DAL' or one of its dependencies.`

Comment: This worked for me also. Quite strangely. So the project .vs/config/applicationhost.config is not overriding the one inside Documents/IISExpress !! Its interesting to see this conversation being going through many years!! :)

Answer (score 8):

If you do:

```
C:\Users\”username*****”\Documents\IISExpress\config
```

You find these file

```
applicationhost.config
aspnet.config
redirection.config
```

Delete above 3 file and then open the project.then the problem is solved. I tried, its working fine.

Comment: this is the right answer guys. and it should be answer.

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio will only report the *filename* it looks for, not the *full path*. The problem for many users is that the IISExpress with the redirection.config can exist in multiple paths, including a OneDrive path which may not be synced.

To figure out exactly what file Visual Studio attempts to open, use the Microsoft (SysInternals) tool ProcMon. It lists all files and resources Windows tries to access. Add a filter for "Path contains redirection.config" and reproduce the problem in Visual Studio. Now you will see the actual path it tries to use.

In my case, I have multiple IISExpress folders. One that was synced to OneDrive and another one that was local. Visual Studio tried to access the OneDrive folder which was not synced to the local disk, and thus it failed.

[image: Forcing IISExpress folder to store files locally resolved the problem]

Comment: This is exactly my problem. I just start the onedrive service/app and then I right clicked the files and selected the "Keep always in this device" option. I use the Brazilian Portuguese version, so the exact command I dont know, but is something like "Keep always". Original: "Manter sempre neste dispositivo" (pt-BR). Worked like a charm. Thanks @https://stackoverflow.com/users/134850/dan-g%c3%b8ran-lunde

Comment: I had the same issue, switched computers and it was picking up the OneDrive version of the IISExpress templates, deleting the folder fixed the issue.

Comment: This worked for me. Onedrive was the culprit.

Answer (score 6):

I have the exact same issue with Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1
I map My Documents folder to SkyDrive, so the IISExpress folder was marked as "Online-only". Once I marked it as "Available offline" everything worked.

Comment: 4 hours later, and this dawned on me.. Not the first time online-only files have reared their ugly heads with unexpected behavior. Shouldn't this kind of stuff 'just work', no different than if I'd tried to open the file directly from explorer?

Answer (score 4):

In some situations simply renaming/deleting the applicationhost.config file isn't enough since VS won't always recreate it for you.  I believe the following will fix it under all circumstances:

Close Visual Studio.

Make sure there are no IIS Express processes running, then delete C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config (where XXXX is your Windows username).

On command line, execute c:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe.  This will recreate the necessary configs.  Press 'Q' straight away to end the process.

Open Visual Studio again and Start/Debug your web project.  Everything should now be working.

Comment: After trying all of the other methods, this finally worked for me

Comment: @JonathanMabe same here

Answer (score 3):

Backup files at local IISExpress folder. It can be found at: C:\Users\”username*****”\Documents\IISExpress\config
Go to the location:
C:\Program Files\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer
Copy the required files from this directory to the local IISExpress folder.
It worked for me after I copied over the files:
applicationhost.config
aspnet.config
redirection.config

Comment: Only thing I had to do, was turn off UseIIS in the project file, and copy the redirection.config to my username's IISExpress config.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the 'My documents' folder for my work laptop was mapped to a network share. So when the work network was not available I was not able to open my solution.

Change:
These will have the value of my docs in network share. Change this to local

I. Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\Personal

II.  Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\Personal

For eg:

Old value: \networkdrive\c$\Users\profile\Documents

New value: C:\Users\profile\Documents

See:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2015/04/01/error-while-runningstarting-a-website-under-iisexpress-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the files in C:\Users\"Your Username"\Documents\IISExpress\config are encrypted. 
Open this folder, Select all the files, Right click and select properties,
Click advanced, deselect "Encrypt contents to secure data, Click okay, click apply.

That will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Using Visual Studio 2013

I had to stop visual studio rename the whole config directory, Documents > IISExpress> Config then start a new web project, which fails but it recreates the config directory, then I rebooted and launched visual studio and everything worked!

I noticed this problem after copying a project between 2 computers, perhaps it was caused by a duplicate IISExpress port or something trivial.

Comment: Yeah, rebooting fixed it for me :-( Checking with ProcMon beforehand showed every access to `*.config` succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Using VS2013 / Windows 7

Close solution. Open Windows Explorer and right-click on "My Documents\IISExpress\config" directory and select "Decrypt". Be sure "Apply changes to this folder, subfolders and files" is selected. Reopen VS solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it happened when IISExpress was still active from a previous VS session and new instance of VS was run.

The solution was to stop (or kill) IIS Express instance.

Comment: This worked for me, too. Tried quite a few of the above options to no avail. Stopped IIS Express then reloaded project.

Project did not have a project file, was just a web site (so just a folder) referenced in a solution file.

Answer (score 1):

Fix was really simple for me >> Restart Visual Studio

My setup:

- Visual Studio 2015
- Web projects use local IIS 8.5
- I occasionally experience what I believe to be a VS bug where it converts some projects to use IISExpress (this is fixed by deleting the folder created in /This PC/Documents). This might be related.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to close Visual Studio or rename anything.

1. Open properties for %userprofile%\Documents
2. Select Security > Advanced, change owner to yourself (again if you are already owner).
3. Select "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects" and "Replace all child object permission entires with inherited permission entires from this object".
4. Ok.

Answer (score 1):

It's 2020, I am reporting the same problem in Visual Studio 2019.

Cause: Multiple VS instances open with different web app (Blazor in my instance).

Solution: Close all VS instances and re-open the solution that you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

For me, It's a simple lack of permission either give everyone permission
to "%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config" this folder or Open VS in Admin mode

Answer (score 1):

for me was removing the file Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

Closing visual studio > Open > Debug

Thanks for the previous answer help go straight to the issue

Answer (score 0):

After trying to solve an issue with a quick fix of changing IIS express inside visual studio from integrated to classic pipeline , I ended up not being able to use IIS express at all.  I tried all techniques above...

I could not rename , copy the file.  Uninstall of IIS express and re-install did not work.

I FINALLY downloaded the latest version of WebMatrix and installed IIS express 8,  that did not work, but at least then i was able to finally delete the old directory and then I recreated itself.....

NOT FUN AT ALL.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this (with vs2013 and windows 7) by going to Documents > IISExpress> Config and renaming the application.config.  After that, I restarted visual studio and opened my project and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue while trying to open another developer's solution after installing VS2013 (Update 3 RC). After following the advice here and deleting/renaming/etc. the `config` folder, VS re-created the files in the wrong location. It created nested `config` folders:

C:\Users[user]\Documents\IISExpress\config\config

I moved everything from ...\config\config into ...\config, and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I found that deleting one of the sites from the applicationhost.config file resolve this problem for me.

I used the following command from the `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IISExpress` directory:

```
appcmd list site
```

then

```
appcmd delete site rogueSiteName
```

Especially there was a site name with a bracketed number suffix (e.g. "MySite(1)") that I deleted.  I'm not sure yet if VS2013 just had an issue with the brackets or that two sites pointed to the same directory.  Either way deleting it made VS happy again.

#### Background

I had been struggling with this issue for a couple of days and nothing seemed to help - not even the instructions given in the top answers here.

I had also tried moving the config folder as mentioned in http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-80-express-readme. But although VS2013 recreated the directory structure and files in the new location the errors continued and running appcmd showed that it was still pointing at the old location by default.

#### Credits

Credit for where I found the commands to use goes to http://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2013/12/02/cleaning-up-iis-express-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.Net Core just access your Properties section, then make a modification and save it.

Example: I modified the SSL port
[image: Core Example]

You will get a notification that your launchsettings.json was modified. Accept that and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

### If it is ASP.NET Core project

Just try to change iis port in file `launchSettings.json` by path `iisSettings:iisExpress:applicationUrl`

Answer (score 0):

On IIS 10 Express. Make sure that Visual Studio (VS) is turned off.

I first found out that `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\` was not working.

I first thought IIS Express had clashed with IIS from the windows OS.

I uninstalled it, yet no changes, then I uninstalled IIS 10 Express that was installed with VS 2019 through the control panel.

Then I went ahead to discover that this file is saved at the `C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Documents\IISExpress`, associated with one drive storage, so I advise you copy `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\` and paste in your windows explorer navigation to find directory.

go to one directory higher, and/or rename the config folder. Restart your VS and run the project again.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was caused by OneDrive. Apparently my documents folder is being synced to it.
What I did is changed the location of the documents folder through regedit and navigated to this path:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > Explorer > User Shell Folders

and then changed the value of **Personal**
from: C:\Users\my username\OneDrive\Documents
to C:\Users\my username\Documents

After that I restart my computer and I was able to create a VS project.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue,
First time, i think Visual Studio not permission access to `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config` so i run Visual Studio with Administrator, but it not working.
I try all answer above but still the error!

Finally, i look internet, i see my onedrive is stopping, **i enable and sync data. Restart computer** and worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstalled OneDrive from your comp