# IISExpress home directory applicationHost.config corruption

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012

Really starting to hate IIS.
Every thing worked fine until today on my Win 8 x64 machine with VS2012 and IIS8 express for .net web development.

It's all to do with the applicationHost.config file, either it is not created at all or created with 0KB. I have tried replacing it with a backup but it just gets overwritten when I try to open a VS2012 project.

Re-installed IIS8 express and the same.

How can I change the default directory it points to? 
This method does not work http://alensiljak.blogspot.ie/2012/06/changing-home-directory-for-iis-express.html as I do not have an entry in HKCU/Software/Microsoft for IISExpress.

[image]

Comment: Did you close all instances of `devenv.exe` and `iisexpress.exe` and preferably reboot your machine before attempting to recreate the file? In my experience the IIS Express configuration easily gets corrupted on a redirected My Documents folder. Try creating the registry key by hand after a reboot.

Comment: is there another location in the registry where I need to add it? As I mentioned beforeI have no IIS folder in the registry location above.

Comment: You can just create the IISExpress key in the registry.

Comment: So create the folders and then just a string key?

Comment: I've just posted an answer to a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897726/iisexpress-8-cannot-read-configuration-file-redirection-config/26800158#26800158

YMMV