# VS 2013 and IIS Express 8 (config File)

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I'm am using VS 2013 and when trying to create an ASP.NET Empty Web Application, I get the error:

> "configuring IIS Express failed with the following error:
>   Filename: redirection.config
>   Error: Cannot read configuration file:"

I have uninstalled and reinstalled both but when I go into ...\Documents\IISExpress the are no config files to move/rename like the suggestions given in previous questions similar to this.

Comment: Oddly, even when i run VS as admin it gives the same exact error

Comment: possible duplicate of [IISExpress 8 Cannot read configuration file redirection.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897726/iisexpress-8-cannot-read-configuration-file-redirection-config)

Comment: problem is, there is no opriginal copy of "applicationhost.config" because my config folder is completely empty. (i removed no files, just uninstall and reinstall)