# Visual Studio 2015 enterprise unknown issue

Tags: visual-studio, unspecified

I'm trying to start a new MVC project but I constantly get this message: Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0X80004005 (E_FAIL)) 
I have tried almost every thing that I could find on internet and still no luck.
My setup: i3 - 250gb ssd - 8gb ram - Windows 10

Comment: Following the top answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897726/iisexpress-8-cannot-read-configuration-file-redirection-config helped me (no need to reinstall).

Answer (score 0):

I've un-installed VS2015 and MSSQL Server 2014 Standard, and I installed VS2013 with SQL Server 2014 Standard, problem solved.