# Creation of virtual directory failed with error : redirection.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, iis-express

My project has web application folder named ABCPortal and this project can't load into VS 2015 whenever I load the whole project . screenshots are attached . any help regarding this will be helpful .

[image]

**UPDATE**

I found this 
http://vivekthangaswamy.blogspot.se/2009/07/aspnet-website-cannot-read.html

as sollution . Can anyone tell me how to do this

**Solution:
1. Add IIS_IUSRS with Read permission on files in the folder
2. Change IIS authentication method to BasicAuthentication
3. refresh the website. It will work**

Comment: Try running it as admin

Comment: already did . no luck :(

Comment: Get rid of the virtual directory, maybe the location of where you are trying to create it to does the have the sufficient permissions. If that is the case, it might be due to application pool identity not having permissions

Comment: thanks for reply :) . can you tell how to get rid of virtual directory cause i searched everything on config folder of iis express but i can't find my project name virtual directory

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qETVU

Comment: thanks umar but i'm using iis express . how to see virtual directories in iis express?

Comment: Ahh okay, go to your documents folder and you will find your application host config file. You can find it here C:\Users\umar.karimabadi\Documents\IISExpress\config. Then search for 'sites' in the config and remove the virtual directory from the config

Comment: in config file i found applicationhost.config , aspnet.config , redirection.config these files and i can't open redirection.config file . i'm adding all these files content in my question

Comment: Look at your projects csproj file. Open it and look for a tag iis express and remove it. This is probably why it does not load because in the csproj file for your website there must be some configuration to set up iis express

Comment: This resolved my issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897726/iisexpress-8-cannot-read-configuration-file-redirection-config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok... now this problem is solved ....

**Solution**

**I searched through net for solution some said to rename application.config in config directory but that didn't worked for me . first I closed visual studio then I rename config directory..voila problem is solved... I hope this will work for others also...** :)

Comment: Bizarre.  Rename the \config directory in \.vs and it recreates a new one and it loads

Comment: @patcapozzi yes that's right renaming the config solved my problem .

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the file in the path "%USERPROFILE\Documents\IISISExpress\config" called "applicationhost.config". Hope it helps :)