# Creation of the virtual directory http:/ /localhost:16858/ failed with the error

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

i am trying to load a web project in VS2015 and i get the following error.

> Creation of the virtual directory http:/ /localhost:16858/ failed with the 
>   error: Filename: redirection.config
>   Error: Cannot read configuration file.

[image]

I tried to delete *.csproj.user to rebuild the file. But it didn't work.

How to solve this problem ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897726/iisexpress-8-cannot-read-configuration-file-redirection-config

Comment: Thanks for your help. İt was useful for me.

Comment: it will be better if you will attach your solution and mark that as an answer because other may still try to solve it and this question will be visible as an unanswered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IISExpress 8 Cannot read configuration file redirection.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897726/iisexpress-8-cannot-read-configuration-file-redirection-config)

Answer (score 5):

The error is solved.

Firstly, if you don't install IIS Express, you should install.

After installing, copy all files from

> C:\Program Files\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer

to

> %userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config