# Not able to run any of the .NET Core web application in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, iis-express-10

When I am trying to run the .NET Core web app in VS2019 Community Edition, I'm getting an error:

[image: Error Message Screenshot]

When I'm creating the template of web app and trying to run it which normally shows hello world in browser but it shows the above error and not able to show output in browser.

Comment: Post the actual error instead of a screen shot. Text in images don't appear in google searches, which means this question wont be able to help anyone else in the future.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IISExpress 8 Cannot read configuration file redirection.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897726/iisexpress-8-cannot-read-configuration-file-redirection-config)

Comment: You could also try launching without IIS Express. At the top of the screen there's a pull down error next to the play button and "IIS Express". Pull that down and launch using the other option.

Comment: i have tried to launch the app without iis express but does not work?