# IIS --> The following error occurred IIS vs 2019

Tags: visual-studio, iis, asp.net-web-api

When I try to run IIS EXPRESS in visual studio 2019  I get the following error message:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtHS2.png)
And I try to move folder asp.net code, repair program, Uninstalls and install agian but I still get the following error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you debug your application from IIS or IIS Express? If you are using IIS Express, I suggest you refer the link below:

[IISExpress 8 Cannot read configuration file redirection.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897726/iisexpress-8-cannot-read-configuration-file-redirection-config).''

And it may also be related to your permissions, I recommend you to run VS as administrator.