# Why is IIS failing to start when I try to debug my web application?

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

*Picture the scene...* I'm on a new PC. I've installed VS15 and SQL Server Express. I've enabled IIS in Windows features. I've pulled my (previously working) ASP.NET MVC project from Git. I press F5 and am pleased to see that the build succeeds, Firefox starts up and things are looking good.

But then, **oh no!** The debug session ends abruptly. Firefox eventually times out.

I've found IIS errors in event viewer that match the timings of my attempts. They reference error code "8007007E". When I put that into the Err.exe utility (as per this article), I get the following:

```
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), Facility: 0x7, Code 0x7e
# for hex 0x7e / decimal 126 :
  SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED                           bugcodes.h
  NMERR_REMOTE_NOT_A_SERVER                                     netmon.h
  SQL_126_severity_15                                           sql_err
# Invalid pseudocolumn '%.*ls'.
  ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND                                           winerror.h
# The specified module could not be found.
# 4 matches found for "8007007E"
```

Which (to me at least) is a bit of a dead-end. I've tried Googling the individual error messages, but can't find anything useful.

I suppose what I'm saying is: **help?** If anyone has any pointers, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK sports fans, we have a resolution on this.

Turns out there were a couple of things wrong here:

1. IIS was being called when IIS express would have been more appropriate. Fixed this by disabling IIS.
2. My `applicationhost.config` had apparently got mangled somehow. Deleting it and recreating my virtual directory (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35799805/50151)) seemed to do the trick.

Hope this is helpful to somebody in the future.