# Debugging not working in ASP.NET Core, or in VS2017 at all

Tags: debugging, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a project, and I have two servers, a login server, and a secondary server which serves the application.

The secondary server is ASP.NET Core, but the first one is just ASP.NET MVC, because I couldn't get Identity to work with tokens for Angular 2, in ASP.NET Core. In Visual Studio 2015, breakpoints worked for ASP.NET MVC, but not for ASP.NET Core.

I moved to Visual Studio 2017 in the hope it would fix things. No breakpoints are hit at all, although my A2 project works, the methods are being called.

The debugger says that there's no debug information for the code.  I've gone in to project settings and told it to generate the full pdb (at the bottom of build settings, under 'advanced'), I've turned off 'just my code' and turned on .NET code breaks. These are all the suggestions I can find online. My breakpoints are still not being hit.

Comment: I found the non CORE one, my global.asax had been moved.  I still can't debug CORE projects in VS2015 or VS2017

Comment: OK, if I create a  new project it works (not surprisingly).  So I will import the code from the other project in to this one until it breaks...

Comment: In my case I had once changed the mode from `Debug` to `Release` but had forgotten to change it back to `Debug`.  In `Release` mode, as one would expect, it would, of course, not hit the `breakpoints`.

Answer (score 21):

This might help someone.

When you are debugging in release, breakpoints will not be hit.

Make sure you select debug when you hit <kbd>F5</kbd> or run.

Comment: Thanks - it was indeed defaulted to release, but I checked that early.  :)

Comment: @PieterdeVries Thank you for sharing your suggestion as it resolved my issue. I had `Release` mode on when installing the app to production but forgot to change the mode back to `Debug`. +1

Answer (score 12):

When attempting to debug a .NET Core web application ensure that you have attached to the correct process. I experienced the same issue the OP described when I was attached to the `w3wp.exe` process.

When I **attached to the `dotnet.exe` process** I was able to break as expected.

*FYI, this was on a .NET Core 2.0 web application.*

The following link is about remote debugging with .NET Core, but parts of it remain applicable.

[Remote Debug ASP.NET Core on a Remote IIS Computer in Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-computer)

**Brief excerpt from link:**

> Type the first letter of a process name to quickly find **dotnet.exe** (for ASP.NET Core).
>   *Note: For an ASP.NET Core app, the previous process name was dnx.exe.*
>
> Click Attach.

Comment: Thank yoouu!!! I have been stuck for 2 days without the debugger! I tried everything but nothing seemed to work until I found this.

Comment: You are a savior. I was trying with `w3wp.exe` for the whole day.

Answer (score 4):

Just change Solution Configurations to *Debug* mode.

You can see it in the attached image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Exit Visual Studio
2. Right click on the short cut for Visual Studio
3. Select - Open File Location
4. Right click on the Visual Studio 2017 file, select Properties
5. Click on Advanced.
6. Run As Administrator --> X == On
7. Apply. OK. OK... blah blah

Comment: This question never had an answer marked.  I landed here with a similar problem, IE simply wouldn't load with the default MVC project and your solution was the answer for me.  Thanks so much; saved me a lot of time.  Now, if you don't mind, why is this required?  I never had to do this before.  Just started using VS2017, so it must be related to this IDE upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me (Visual Studio 2017):

1. Open the project properties
2. Open the *Build* tab
3. [Click on *Advanced...*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRr9K.png)
4. [Set *Debugging information* to FULL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEgOY.png)
5. Clean and rebuild

Comment: Working solution! Thanks, Olavo! I had 'Portable' option selected for 'Debugging Information'

Answer (score 1):

As I'm working on an API project I had unticked 'Launch Browser' in the project properties. Breakpoints only worked when I ticked this again.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems I got a web.config file from somewhere, like this:

```
   <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

I don't know how it got here, but if I comment it out, debugging works...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `"launchBrowser": true,` in file launchSettings.json was removed accidentally, I put it back and the breakpoints were hit.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an IIS Express problem

[image]

Check possible fixes here:

[Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873126/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server)