# Unable to launch IIS express error Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on an Asp.Net MVC5 project and I have done quite of work on it, i tried to manage the architecture of my app by moving common functionality to a common project to remove unnecessary dependencies, so i removed references to those nuget packages DLLs and manually deleted them from bin directory instead of uninstalling, after that i rebuild the entire solution which was successful but VS is not hosting it to IIS Express and i'm getting following error dialog. Can any one help me out if possible.
Note: I have tried some solutions at Stack Overflow but those are not working in my case and also my other project's hosting is working fine.
[Error Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7vV1.png)

Comment: Tried looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873126/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the right solution to my problem. I just deleted the .vs folder which was hidden in my solutions directory and after that IIS is launching smoothly.
Don't worry just delete the .vs folder visual studio will recreate it with new **applicationhost.config** file which is where host configuration is living.

Answer (score 0):

- Right-click on your solution and select Properties
- Select “Web” from the left
- Under “Use local IIS server” change the port number

Comment: [msdn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/finbar_ryan/2013/01/02/debugging-the-unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-error-from-visual-studio-2012)