# "Unable to Launch the IIS Express Web Server" (UseIIS vs. UseIISExpress)

Tags: visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

Using Visual Studio 2012, suddenly we are getting the error "Unable to Launch the IIS Express Web Server" and the answer is NOT to change the port number, so please don't suggest that. The answer is also NOT to delete the IIS Express folder or the applicationHost.config file ... none of those solutions worked. The only thing that could get any of the programs to run is changing "UseIIS" to false in the .csproj file, while keeping "UseIISExpress" set to true.

```
<UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
<UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
```

If I flip them (UseIIS=true and UseIISExpress=false) it will not run, same error.  On a co-worker's PC both values are set to true and that person does not have any issues with running projects.  What could be causing this inconsistency and how can we fix this so that we don't have to edit every single .csproj file to get programs to run?  We work with over 100 programs so this isn't ideal.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html#background If you don't reveal all relevant settings, it is impossible to tell what is inconsistent.

Comment: I'm really not sure what other relevant settings to reveal.  I'm happy to share settings that are relevant though, what else is needed?

Comment: Run the diagnostics and edit your question to include the report. The tool collects most such settings.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to pinpoint the problem directly according to an error message. We have to try every solution to troubleshoot it.
This kind of issue happens frequently on the Win7 machine with VS2012.
Lots of people post questions pertaining to this issue on SO, We have to find which solution is appropriate for us.
[Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873126/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server)
On my side, I choose to repair it and run VS with the Administrator account again. It worked perfectly.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.