# Visual Studio unable to launch the IIS Express Web Server

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-express

I am using Windows server 2019 and IIS v10.  When I run Debug in Visual Studio (2022) the project builds successfully but then gives the message "unable to launch the IIS Express Web Server."  Target framework is 4.5.  Using SSL with the development certificate but same error without the SSL.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanking you in anticipation.

Roger

I've applied all the suggestions in this forum to no avail.

Comment: ...is IIS Express installed?

Comment: I deleted the iisexpress folder and its contents, ran Debug and the folder was recreated.  Does that mean it is installed?

Comment: What happens if you create a clean project from scratch, such as `dotnet new mvc`. Does IIS Express fail even on that project?

Comment: There are many reasons for this error, you can use the solutions in these links as a reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/17038432/13336642](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17038432/13336642) or [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1191901/unable-to-launch-iis-express-web-server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1191901/unable-to-launch-iis-express-web-server).