# Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server in vs 2017

Tags: visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2017, iis-express, virtual-directory

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 solution. When I try to run it using Visual Studio 2017, I get following error: Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server.
how to fix this error?

right click on project , create virtual directory

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873126/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server

Answer (score 0):

This problem is probably caused by the port being occupied, please try the following steps:

1. Find the path of solution and navigate to <path_to_solution_folder>.vs\config\applicationhost.config
2. Check the configuration of  section have any problem in your site.

Or you can close the VS solution and delete the applicationhost.config file and re-open the solution, and then check if it works fine.