# Unable to launch IIS Express Web Server in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I have an application in MVC 4 using VS 2013.

This is very strange,everything was working fine till last night but today morning when I started working and tried to run my application I found the following error:

```
Unable to launch IIS express web server.
Failed to register URL"http://localhost:62707" for site...
Access denied(0x80070005)
```

I searched regarding this since morning and I got solutions for this which I tried as:

- I deleted  IIS Express folder from my documents several times and
  tried running the application by reopening it but that dint work.
- I tried with changing the binding in applicationhost file from http
  to https. With this the  only thing that got changed is the error is
  now showing:

  > Unable to launch IIS Express Web server.
  >       The start URL specified is not valid.
- I restarted my system many times as per some of the suggestion . Also
  my browser too .
- I tried ending the process for IIS Express from Task Manager.

But nothing seems to be working for me and even after trying almost all of the possibilities for hours I kind of got stuck at this point.

Comment: I missed that point while posting but I already tried with running as administrator and that's not working too.Also My Documents is accessible here.

Comment: "The start URL specified is not valid.". Oh. Just check project settings in VS and fix the url, e.g. add http://, etc.

Comment: I checked @abatishchev ..its proper there.Again I tried with opening application and again I am getting the earlier access denied error.

Comment: Hey This worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/42666889/6860557
if any else is still having the problem

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You can try this:**

- Open "Command Line Interface (CLI)" called "Command shell" with
  "Win+R" write "cmd" put this command for removing the urlacl.

  ```
  netsh http delete urlacl url=http://{ip_address}:{port}/
  ```
- Then add the url for everyone

  ```
  netsh http add urlacl url=http://{ip_address}:{port}/ user=everyone
  ```
- Then close the VS and delete the IISExpress folder from Documents 
  path as:

  ```
  %userprofile%\Documents, e.g. C:\Users\[you]\Documents\IISExpress
  ```
- Re-run your application.

Comment: worked for me as well. Didn't happen until I used ccleaner and ccleaner's registry cleaner on my PC and restarted.

Comment: Thanks Vishal, this solved my problem.   As a note, you can view all the reserved URLs with:      `netsh http show urlacl`

Comment: In cmd I got error as:   URL reservation delete failed, Error: 2
The system cannot find the file specified.