# The start URL specified is not valid. http://localhost:xxx

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure, iis

Today morning when I tied to run my project I get "The start URL specified is not valid" error". I just install the newest Azure SDK.

[image]

In IIS Manager I see this, I can't start, restert website.

[image]

Why I can't run my project, any ideas? I have no logs in Event Logs. I use VS2015 Ultimate.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440060/unable-to-launch-iis-express-web-server-in-vs-2013

Comment: I have no info about access denied, I think I have problem with start IIS

Comment: Are you sure IIS express is installed, what does it say in event viewer?

Comment: I have 100% of sure, Yesterday it works

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873126/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server) (bad IIS config file).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It could be a short answer but I too had this problem after deleting IISExpress folder inside this path

> "C:\Users\{username}\Documents"

after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873126/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server) article.

but I solved this problem by doing these steps.

1)Run [Visual studio as Administrator](https://ppolyzos.com/2017/08/08/always-run-visual-studio-as-administrator/)

2)Uncheck [Override application root Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43888687/what-does-override-application-root-url-really-do)

[image]

then run just hit launch project.

Answer (score 3):

I was playing w/ things and I guess I accidentally cleared this setting. 
Different from other answers here, but the message does say 'Start url...'
I set it back to 'localhost:4300' and was back plodding along.

[image: Project Properties]

Answer (score 1):

I Know it's very late, but for future developers who come across this,
i just had the same problem and i was using IIS Express,
1st i deleted then re-added the ip with netch commands:

- netsh http delete urlacl url=http://192.168.1.76:49603/
- netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.1.76:49603/ user=everyone
- netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="HNclinic3" dir=in protocol=tcp 
  localport=49603 profile=private remoteip=localsubnet action=allow

But then the error message was still showing, all i did then was go to the properties in my app (right click> properties> web) and under Project Url these is a checkBox.

- Override application root Url

I unchecked it and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just restart your visual studio will do. Everything will be fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was restart Visual Studio 2017 CE.