# What does Override application root URL really do?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015, virtual-directory

The only place on the entire internet I could find an explanation is on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983445.aspx):

> Specifies an alternative path for the application root URL. Use this
>   option if the Web application root is not the root of your project.

From [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/01/03/application-root-is-your-friend/) I understood that "application root" is the path that retrieves when using tilde in ASP.NET. So I would expect that if I go to project's properties - Web - "Override application root" and specify another url then the tilde would map to that url.

But it doesn't. For example my web is on a virtual directory - `http://localhost/WebApplication1`
and on "Override application root" I try to specify `http://localhost/WebApplication2` or `http://localhost` or `http://WebApplication2` (which all exist on my local IIS). Now when I write

```
Response.Redirect("~/test2/login");
```

I expect it to redirect me to `http://localhost/WebApplication2/test2/login`.
But instead it redirects me to `http://localhost/WebApplication1/test2/login` as if I didn't override the "application root".

So what does this feature really suppose to do? Or maybe it's not working because I'm missing something and didn't define it properly?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Override application root URL doesn't change where the Application root is within your application. It changes the URL used to reach the application root. Because IIS does some hostname verification it's used to specify if you want to reach your application by a means other than `localhost:[PORT]`.

For instance, if you override it to `www.myapp.com` you can then reach your application by adding this to your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1     www.myapp.com
```

This might be especially useful if you're making your application available to a remote device (a virtual machine on your computer, or a mobile device on your network) because they would be unable to navigate to `localhost` as the application address.

Comment: Good answer, I was looking for an explanation all over and couldn't find anywhere! I still don't understand though why is this needed, because I could just add a binding on IIS to that website and define in the "Host name" `www.myapp.com` - it seems that it would achieve the exact same effect?

Comment: If you're using IISExpress for local development there isn't much of a GUI that I can see for configuring things like that. As far as I can tell, you can either use that option in the build config or manually edit the IISExpress config files.