# "Failed to Register URL" error in VS 2015

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

[image]

I have been getting this error 5-10 times a day ever since upgrading to VS 2015.

What have I done:

1. Verified the sites are properly registered in the applicationhost.config file
2. Reserved the port via netstat - didn't work
3. Used the netstat command -aon : find ":61414" (my port) and nothing is using the port
4. Checked task manager: ISS EXPRESS is not running

Work around: Sometimes this error is easy to fix, all I have to do is close Chrome and IIS starts working again.  Other times I have to restart VS, and other times still **(most of the time)** I have to restart my computer.

Comment: You can have multiple versions of Visual Studio on your computer.  My suggestions would be to downgrade Visual Studio to the Version you used to have and install Visual Studio 2015 separately, so you can have 2.  And of course you would need to have enough hard drive space.  For the 2015 version, you would need between 5.05 GB to 37 GB.  Not sure about the version you used to have.

Comment: It sounds like maybe somehow when you're closing the app, iis express isnt shutting down in between and the process for your site is still spinning. Does its behavior change if you halt your av ?

Comment: @Auguste - VS 2015 is the only VS I have ever had on this PC (Had to wipe HD several months ago, only installed 2015)

Comment: @BugFinder - I don't have permissions to halt MY AV, I have looked in the task manager and IIS is not running when this happens

Comment: After I read the error message again, the problem is not with Visual Studio.  I had the problem before, but I don't remember how I fixed it.  I always had to end the processes through Task Manager in order to run the application again.

Comment: Hmm, are you using a mapped on demand SQL file? ive had VS do that when it thinks debug still has the file open - just wondering if its not really an web site issue more some file its using

Comment: Use Jexus Manager http://jexusmanager.com to check if there is any conflicting reserved URL under HTTP API page.

Comment: Are you launching VS as an Administrator?

Comment: @Jacob G - yes I am

Comment: VS2015 creates a hidden folder .vs under the same folder as your solution file. Under this is a config folder containing applicationhost.config. Deleting this file (or the entire .vs folder) then starting VS2015 to recreate it can fix this error.

Comment: @krish - Thanks, I tried your suggestion but it did not work.

Comment: this might help you -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660366/unable-to-launch-web-server

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me last week, i did the following;

- Exit Skype (No need to uninstall)
- Exit Apache/Wamp server
- Reinstall IIS express

The error hasn't come back to me since, i also followed this to keep IIS running after debug;

Right click your project > click Properties > select the 'Web' tab on the left > uncheck the Enable Edit and Continue checkbox.

Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

One thing is already using **IIS**' port (usually **80**) another **IIS** or **other localhost servers** is running on background process. Take a look at the **Task Manager**.

Comment: this is a dev machine.  And as stated in the original question I used netstat to determine nothing was using the port and IIS was not running

Comment: maybe you should check firewall or antivirus applications

Answer (score 0):

this error is may be something with up-gradation of vs this link might help

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/883825

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by running the command:

`iisreset /restart`
(under admin mode)

I think IIS is releasing its lock on resources.