# How to fix port 52493 is in use

Tags: visual-studio, iis

[image]

always show this notification if i running project.

Comment: Most likely you have 2 (or more) web projects running explicitly on this port - check your project's properties and change conflicting ports or switch to auto-assign ports. There's not enough information to provide a complete answer.

Comment: close all the instances for iis. Check the processes and see which one is using this port. Alternatively, u can set to have dynamic ports while running multiple web projects

Comment: Check if you are in the situation explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660366/unable-to-launch-web-server/14660479#14660479

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because 52493 currently used by another application, another solution you can change your visual studio iis express port by following these steps :

1. Right click on your project name
2. Choose properties
3. Choose Web on the left side tab
4. On server section change port on the project URL box
5. Click Create Virtual Directory
6. Save the configuration (Ctrl + S)
7. Try Running your web apps again

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have another site also started on the same port and it is still running.Otherwise another process is using the same port.

If you have already checked everything and still not able to find out,follow these steps to figure out who is using this port.

`netstat -ano | find "52493"`

This command will list the process which is using that port. You can match the process Id by cross checking with task manager or following command.

`tasklist |find "<pid>"`

If you find that pid 4 is using this port,then some website configured in IIS  or iisexpress is using this port.PID 4 is system process which is used by http service( http.sys) which is what IIS or Iisexpress or any other process (e.g WCF service listening using httplistener ) uses internally.

Now if the command line is little difficult,you can use [tcpview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) tool from sys internals. This shows all the connections active in the system with which process is using it .

You can also easily close the connection forcefully and make the port free just by right clicking on a particular connection.

Hope this helps!