# Why and how to fix? IIS Express "The specified port is in use"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express

We know a random port number is assigned to a web application in Visual Studio. It works fine in my office desktop. But when I pull the code onto my laptop (from VisualStudio.com) and run the web app. I got a message, saying,

## The specified port is in use

Port 10360 is already being used by another application.

### Recommendations

1. Try switching to port other than 10360 and higher than 1024.
2. Stop the application that is using port 10360.

---

I can fix it using `Recommendation #1` by changing the port into something else like 13333. But I am very curious what happened to port 10360. How can I check what application is using port 10360? How can I stop that application?

Comment: i had the same problem. My issue was that i had several web projects in the same solution. Even though they were not running . One of the other projects used the same port. Just make sure any given project uses its own port.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

i solve the problem this way...

**File** -> **Open** -> **Web Site...**
[image]

After that select **Local IIS**  under **IIS Express Site**
remove the unwanted project.

hope this help.

Comment: I had to restart after doing this.

Comment: Where is select Local IIS under IIS Express Site

Comment: This step did not fix mine issue. After following the steps, I restarted Visual Studio as well but no gain.

Comment: After I did this I get the error "unable to connect to webserver iisexpress" when trying to run the solution.

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/66290952/7084222

Answer (score 126):

I had a similar issue running Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10. 
Some solutions that worked for others seemed to include:

1. Changing the application port number.
2. Have Visual studio automatically assign a port number each time the application start.
3. Restart Visual Studio
4. Restart the computer.

Unfortunately, none of these solutions worked for me, assigning another port number did work but was not an acceptable solution as it was important for my application to run on a specified port.

**The Solution**

First I ran the command:

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::
```

from an elevated command-line process. This solved the initial error, when attempting to run the application I no longer got the "port in use" error, instead, I now got an error stating the application was unable to bind to the port because administrative privileges were required. (although I was running Visual Studio as administrator)

The second error was caused by Hyper-V that adds ports to the Port Exclusion Range, the port my application uses was in one of these exclusion ranges. 
You can view these ports by running the following command: `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`

To solve this second error:

1. Disable Hyper-V: Control Panel-> Programs and Features-> Turn Windows features on or off. Untick Hyper-V
2. Restart the computer.
3. Add the port you are using to the port exclusion range: `netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=50403 numberofports=1 store=persistent`
4. Reenable Hyper-V
5. Restart the computer

From here everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Wow, the only thing that got me to the solution.  Disabling Hyper-V got me a Windows 10 frowny BSOD thanks to the corporate build, but thanks to `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp` I was at least able to pick a new port for the project.

Comment: DUDE Not only was this the correct answer, you actually explained it instead of just dumping a CMD script (which is fine btw for most cases). Thank you so much, would upvote 100x if I could.

Comment: Thank you, this happened to me after installing docker.

Comment: This saved me, I spent all my days and was very frustrated. This leads me to the correct solution. https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3171#issuecomment-459205576

Comment: Had this issue due to Hyper-V. Thanks for this!

Comment: @PhilipTrenwith Detailed one :). Optionally, for a quick solution, unblocked ports can be used as in my answer.

Comment: @PhilipTrenwith Sir, you are a lifesaver. Spend hours figuring this out and your solution fixed it. I also had the issue after setting up docker.

Comment: Note: You don't need to disable and re-enable Hyper-V if you're happy just picking a port that isn't in those ranges. In my case the SSL port was fine but the non-SSL port was excluded, changing it make everything work without registering :: or disabling Hyper-V.

Comment: I can't upvote this answer enough. I could run it on a different port but randomly selecting a different port kept getting the same error. This gave me the list of unallowed ports so I could intelligently choose one that would work.

Comment: this is the way

Comment: This did not work for me. I ended up disabling Hyper-V and leaving it off. Which got me past the port issue, but it hasn't resolved all of the issues running the sites..

Comment: After trying many solutions. Finally this worked for me. It was the issue related to docker which I installed. I had to disable virtualization from Bios as there is no option in control panel to disable(Windows 11). thanks

Comment: The issue can happen by starting two visual studio sessions at the same exact time.  They both try to access the same port.  Before trying the above, just restart your machine.  Then start the visual studio sessions a minute or more apart.

Comment: @RobertSmith I think that is what happened with me, that I started two instances of Visual Studio in quick succession. I still had to follow all of the steps in this answer to fix the issue, but in trying to figure out what changed to cause this issue, starting two instances of Visual Studio is the only thing I can confirm that did happen. To the best of my knowledge there wasn't a windows update and there was nothing new (like Docker) that was installed that could have introduced the issue.

Comment: Nice job Phil, this helped me

Answer (score 50):

**SIMPLE SOLUTION THAT WORKED FOR ME:** (Credits to combination of other's answers)

```
**My System Info:**
Windows 10 build : 1809
IIS Version      : 10.0.17763.1
Hyper-V          : Enabled
Docker           : Installed - 2.3.0.2 (45183)
```

- Check for blocked ports range in CMD (admin)

  ```
  >> netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp

  (Sample output):
  Protocol tcp Port Exclusion Ranges
  Start Port    End Port
  ----------    --------
  49696       49795         (SEE HERE, 49796 to 49895 is not blocked)
  49896       49995
  ... list goes on ...
  ```
- Open Visual Studio and Navigate to > Project > Properties > Web > Servers > Project Url
- Use the Port that is not blocked.

  ```
  (Sample port):
  http://localhost:49796/
  ```
- Restart Visual Studio (if required)
- Have a coffee and share love. (required) :)

Comment: any idea why certain range is being blocked ?

Comment: that is thanks for right answer for me ;)

Comment: This worked for me! Wish I saw this first! I tried EVERYTHING! Would be nice if IIS could auto detect this???

Answer (score 42):

1. change it in solution (right Click) -> **property** -> **web** tab
2. Click **Create Virtual Directory** (in front of project Url textbox)

[image: IIS Express port change for fixing port in use]

Comment: I don't want to change my .sln property page over and over again. In my case, the port defined on the property page (as you've shown above) becomes locked when I do something in Visual Studio that causes Visual Studio to crash.

Comment: @bkwdesign , i have no idea about the crash , maybe you should run with Admin Privilege and also create virtual directory or update your VS to latest version or at last just switch to standard IIS Role

Answer (score 39):

This was haunting me for over a year!

For me,

- no website was running iin IIS Express
- nothing was using the port as determined by running: `netstat -ano` at the command line.

The solution was to run

`netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::`

from the command line.

Happy days, and credit to: James Bryant! https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/110767/specified-port-is-in-use.html

Comment: no idea what happened, no idea what that command does, but it worked where other solutions here failed

Comment: This command broke my IIS, be careful running this. Had to run netsh http delete iplisten ipaddress=:: for my local IIS sites to work again.

Comment: Broke my IIS as well, it started saying it needs Administrative privileges to run. Had to revert it.

Comment: For those getting Administrator priviledge issues after this, look at  @Philip Trenwith's answer, it could be Hyper-V excluded port ranges.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem, but no proccess appeared neither in netstat nor in resmon.

What solved the problem for me was closing all the open browser windows.

Comment: Wow. That worked for me too. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Confirming that this sometimes fixes the problem (using Firefox as standard browser), and it makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: This didnt work for me.  No running apps.  Just a port in use.  No running web pages.  Just an error.  What a pain.

Comment: I think the reason this works is when you make a web request the browser is using an arbitrary number for the *source* port (usually between 49152 - 65535) and this is conflicting with the port configured in IIS

Comment: This worked for me too. It didnt make sense as the app blocking the port had no reason to be using it.

Answer (score 28):

The cause of this issue in my own case is a bit different. Everything was working fine until I started docker to do some other stuff. Starting docker, in one way or the other, added some new ranges of ports to the Port Exclusion Ranges. What to do:

1. Open command prompt (As an administrator)
2. run: netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp (You should see the port your application is using in the excluded port ranges)
3. run: net stop winnat
4. run: netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp (by this time, the Administered port exclusions ranges should reduce)
5. run net start winnat.

If the problem was caused by Windows NAT Driver (winnat), then you should be good by now.

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: It worked for me, in my scenario the problem occured after 'cleaning-up' the docker images, it seems the port was locked for one of the images and the docker clean-up removed the image but didn't deallocate the port. after that process, the port was not even showing in netstat, even restarting the machine didn't help. but net stop/start helped.. very weird.

Comment: helped on Win11 Pro for IIS Express related issues

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: VS 2022 will sometimes keep the port open when showing Swagger docs through IIS. This solution solves the reserved port.

Answer (score 20):

You're looking for `netstat`.

Open an administrative command shell and run

`netstat -aob`

And look for port 10360. It'll show you what executable opened the port and what PID to look up in Task Manager. (Actually, run `netstat -?` in an unprivileged shell first, because I don't approve of blindly running anything you don't understand, especially in a privileged context.)

Here's what the switches do:

`-a` shows all connections or open ports, not just active ones - the port you want is probably listening, not active.

`-o` shows the owning PID of the connection or port, so you can find the process in Task Manager's Processes tab. (You might need to add the PID column in Task Manager. View->Select Columns)

`-b` shows the binary involved in opening the connection or port. This is the one that requires elevated access.

Comment: That's neat. Now I at least have the `PID` of the application. Thanks.

Comment: That command will generate a lot of noise, so if you want to cut straight to the offending application, pipe the results to findstr like so: `netstat -aob | findstr '10360'`

Comment: All the other answers sent me off in the woods, this one actually allowed me to find the source and fix the problem.

Comment: Also, you can use nestat -aob -p TCP to only view TCP ports

Answer (score 13):

1. Close the VS

   2. Start again - right click and run as admin
   3. Run your project again.

Comment: if suppose that port is used by some another process changes port in project >properties > debug 
then run as admin works

Comment: It's pretty sad but this worked.  Nothing else worked.  The error is compeletely wrong as I had no running processes under the port in question.  This appears to be a bug from visual studio and IISExpress.  It makes no sense why I had to close it out and run it again.

Comment: This step did not fix mine issue.

Comment: Happy and disturbed that one admin run is what it took after reboots, port changes, process kills, netstat hunts, iplisten changes. Continued to work when run as user.

Comment: For me as well, of all the solutions here, this is the one that worked for me. Why, oh why?

Answer (score 8):

Running visual studio in administrative mode solved my issue

Answer (score 6):

1. Delete the .sln file, if you have one.
2. Open the file C:\Users\NN\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
3. Locate the problematic site in configuration/system.applicationHost/sites and delete the whole site section.
4. "Open Web Site.." from Visual Studio and the project will be given a random new port.

Comment: This is still a best solution.

Answer (score 6):

For me the "The specified port is in use" error is usually fixed (well actually worked arround) by **stopping** the "Internet Connection Sharing (**ICS**)" (SharedAccess) and the "World Wide Web Publishing Service" (**W3SVC**) service.

After the project / ISS Express is started the stopped services can be started again without issues.

Whenever i receive the error **the port (in the 50000 range) is definitely not in use** (checked with netstat & tcpview).

It would be nice if Microsoft did some integration testing of Visual Studio / IIS Express along side with HyperV and the "normal" IIS Service OR gave some guidance on which port ranges to use for VS / IIS Express (and which ports to avoid).

Comment: This was my issue and it took forever to track down because ICS apparently doesn't show up in netstat or Resource Monitor.  Thanks! 
 Stupid $%@*&&!)$*!

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this. This is the only thing that worked for me. I think it happened in between things working for web app development and then electing to share my Android phone internet connection via USB to my computer. And I did try everything, from the <netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::> idea above (breaks things and needs to be deleted), to attempting to delete the reserved range (get access denied even as an administrator). Restarts, closing web browsers, etc, did not work until I tried this, so thanks again.

Comment: Stopping ICS in Services fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

**Visual studio 2015**

- Close all the files you have open inside Visual studio.
- Then close application and exit Visual Studio.
- Open Visual Studio and it should successfully run.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the ports. Read the question please.

Comment: i already read the question then only i reply it happened with me also and i did the same what i have written in the post and it works for me.

Comment: I guess it's okay then.

Comment: This fixed it for me. So many issues are fixed by just restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: This just fixed it for me. I have no idea what UmarZaii is complaining about.

Answer (score 5):

#### netstat didn't show anything already using the port

`netstat -ano | findstr <your port number>` showed nothing for me. I found out that port was excluded using this command to see what ranges are reserved by something else:

`netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`

You can try to unblock the range from the start port for a number of ports (need Command Prompt with Administrator):

`netsh int ip delete excludedportrange protocol=tcp numberofports=<number of ports> startport=<start port>`

However, in my case I couldn't unblock the range, I just got "Access is denied", so I ended up having to pick another port for my site.

My original solution: The only thing that worked was deleting the .vs folder in the solution folder. (I've since found you can just delete the .vs/config/applicationhost.config instead to avoid losing so many settings).

Comment: I thought this solution would work well but I still get the error.  
The port in question for me (3333) isn't appearing in netstat -a at all.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh this problem reoccurred for me & I've found out additional info why so I've updated my answer. You might be in the same boat as me, the port was not in use but reserved (excluded) by something else.

Comment: Nothing is using these ports. Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/66290952/7084222

Comment: this did it for me, somehow Windows all of a sudden had added my port number in the range of excludedportranges. using the netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp showed me what range was available.

Answer (score 3):

If netstat doesn't show anything, try a reboot.

For me, nothing appeared in netstat for my port.  I tried closing Google Chrome browser windows as @Clangon and @J.T. Taylor suggested, but to no avail.

In the end a system reboot worked, however, so I can only assume that something else was secretly holding the port open.  Or perhaps it just took longer than I was prepared to wait for the ports to be released after Chrome shut down.

Comment: Exactly my scenario!

Answer (score 3):

For me, close all application and restart the computer.

When window start, Open Visual studio first, then open browser and click run(F5).

Now it works. I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

Open Task Manager and Just Close all processes of 'IIS Express System Tray' and 'IIS Express Worker Process' and Re-run the Project

[image: Task Manager Process Details]

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue follow the steps below:

1. Open a CMD prompt in Administrator mode
2. Then execute the command:
   **netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::**
3. After that, run the project

Comment: what the heck did that do?

Answer (score 1):

For me, the Google Chrome browser was the process which was using the port. Even after I closed Chrome, I found that the process still persisted (I allow Chrome to "run in background" so that I can receive desktop notifications). I went into Task Manager, and killed the Chrome browser process, and then started my web application, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Open your csproj with for example Notepad ++ and scroll down to DevelopmentServerPort. Change it to something else as long as it's above 1024 like rekommended (so for example 22312). Also change the IISUrl to http://localhost:22312/. Save your changes and restart the project.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was no application using specified port and elevated running of Visual Studio didn't help either.

What worked for me is to reinstall IIS Express and than restart computer.

Comment: This was the only option that worked for me on Windows 10 1809 with VS 2017.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was an orphaned **VBCSCompiler** task from a previous run, that didn't shut down and was somehow interfering. Killing that task solved it.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/31482/vbcscompiler-does-not-shut-down.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to configre this parameter by running the following in the administrative command prompt:

> netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::

Answer (score 0):

click on the notification present on bottom of the task bar if you receiving the error like port in use then select the iiss icon right click then click on exit ,it work like charm for me

Answer (score 0):

I had same error showing up. I had my web service set as an application in IIS and I fixed it by:

Right-click on my WebService project inside my solution  > Properties > Web > Under 'Servers' change from IIS Express to Local IIS (it will automatically create a Virtual Directory which is what you want)

Answer (score 0):

When Port xxxx is already being used, there's always a PID (Process Id) elaborated with the error. Simply go to the task manager on the machine you are running the application, click on details, and you will identify what the other application is. You can then decide whether you want to end that process or not

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this, I had the full IIS feature turned on for one of my machines and it seemed to cause this to happen intermittently.

I also got random complaints about needing Admin rights to bind sites after a while, I assume that somehow it was looking at the full IIS config (Which does require admin as it's not a per-user file).

If you are stuck and nothing else is helping (and you don't want to just choose another port) then check you have removed this if it is present.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I tried tons of these options and I didn't get anywhere.  Then I realized I had installed VMWare Player just before the issue started.  I uninstalled it, and this error went away.

I'm sure there's some way to make them coexist, but I don't really need Player so I just removed it.  If you've tried all kinds of stuff and it's not working consider looking through any programs you've installed recently (especially those that deal with network adapters?) and see if that gets you anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017, select Project/Properties and then select the Web option. In the IIS section next to the default project URL click Create Virtual Directory. This solved the problem for me. I think in my case the default project Virtual Directory had been corrupted in some way following a debugging session.

Answer (score 0):

For me only thing worked is removing the  element containing my application name, path and binding info under
</system.applicationHost> element in
applicationhost file.
To be found under C:\Users\yourUsername\Documents\IISExpress\config

Closed the the solution , deleted the bad site element , save the applicationhost file and close.
Reopen the application/Website from Visual studio using Admin rights - Rebuilt and Run. Voila... A new port is auto assigned to your application which solves the purpose.

Can also be verified without running-- check the Properties window for the solution and URL will have new port number.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got also this issue from my ASP Core 3.1 projets.
I thing that for some reason visual studio ignore the IP/Port setting in the project property and start it on 5000 and 5001. I discovered this while attempting to start my Core 3.1 projects from prompt using **dotnet run**

And this post helped me
[How to specify the port an ASP.NET Core application is hosted on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365277/how-to-specify-the-port-an-asp-net-core-application-is-hosted-on)

It suggest to

- Specify the port in the appsettings.json or maybe appsettings.development.json. (see lower)
- Close Visual Studio
- Delete /.vs, /bin, /obj folders
- Restart Visual Studio.

appsettings.json / appsettings.development.json content

```
 {   
      /***************************
      "Urls": "http://localhost:49438", <==== HERE
      /***************************/
      
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Warning",
          "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*",
      "connectionStrings": { ...  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do these,

1. stop the running project
2. close the browser(s)
3. run the project

Answer (score -1):

The same error was appearing in my Visual Studio 2021. After installing Docker every port was engaged by Kubernetes.WDS.

Simple 2-step solution:

1. Disable Hyper-V: *Control Panel* -> *Programs and Features* -> Turn Windows features on or off. Untick *Hyper-V*.
2. Restart the computer.