# IIS Express Web Server Port Is In Use

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I can normally debug my web service with no problem, but now I persistently get error "Unable to launch the IIS Express Web Server. Port 3268 is in use". I have looked at previous questions about this, but I am stuck:

- it doesn't matter what port I use
- rebooting, closing web browser, deleting web history etc all fail
- tools like TCPView show that the port is NOT in use
- I can start/stop IISExpress from a command prompt OK
- normally, address localhost:3268 shows an error message in a browser - but after loading the project in Visual Studio (and BEFORE starting to debug the project, or doing anything at all to it), localhost:3268 shows a web page in the browser

Comment: View my Answer on this Thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572897/why-and-how-to-fix-iis-express-the-specified-port-is-in-use/50234608#50234608

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why and how to fix? IIS Express "The specified port is in use"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572897/why-and-how-to-fix-iis-express-the-specified-port-is-in-use)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link that Krishna provided inspired me to open IIS and discover that there was a local web site in IIS with the same port (it was the same web service). I deleted that, and now I can debug my application again.

I cannot explain why I couldn't see the port in use, why it started offering the web page when the project was loaded in Visual Studio, and why I couldn't see that IIS was running in the task manager. I am guessing that Visual Studio was actually running it somehow.

Thanks to all respondents for their help!

Comment: When the website runs via IIS, there is a Process named w3wp.exe in the task manager. That indicates that the website is running via IIS

Answer (score 14):

I was having these issues with specific projects.

For me,

- no website was running iin IIS Express
- nothing was using the port as determined by running: `netstat -ano` at the command line.

The solution was to run

`netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::`

from the command line.

Happy days, and credit to: James Bryant! https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/110767/specified-port-is-in-use.html

Comment: I have no idea what this does, but it worked for me.

Comment: I tried it but it seems any website on IIS will stop working, only IIS express will work!

Comment: One of the posts on the link you provided suggested that I stop the web site that used the port via IIS Admin.  That worked. I was able to add the web site service reference and then restart the web site.

Answer (score 6):

You can change the port of the website from the website properties under the web ribbon, specifying a different port other than 3268.

Also a link from the Stackoverflow discusses the same scenario

[Why and how to fix? IIS Express "The specified port is in use"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572897/why-and-how-to-fix-iis-express-the-specified-port-is-in-use)

Answer (score 1):

1, firs click properties.

[image: 1. click properties]

2. Click web tab and in servers section change the port number. (simply increment or decrement the last digit

After that click "Create Virtual Directory" button. Then debug and run. 
[image: Click web tab and in servers section change the port number]

I hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual Studio and delete the .vs folder (in the same folder where the .sln file is located.

[image]