# IIS Express 'The specified port is in use' Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis-express

Apologies about the long message, but I thought I should let you know what I have already tried.

I've very recently started learning C# through Visual Studio and all was going OK until about three weeks ago. I clicked on the button with a green triangle which did the usual thing of launching the internet page, but the site never loads. I then noticed there was an ISS Express notification which brings up the following (can't figure out how to get my cropped screen shot on here):

'The Specified port is in use
Port 49665 is already being used by process "svchost.exe" (process ID "2112")
Recommendations

1. Try switching to port other than "49665" and higher than 1024
2. Stop the application that is using port "49665"'

I have managed to locate the svchost.exe on my computer and it is in the system 32 folder. There doesn't appear to be an option to stop it, and I am worried deleting it will break my operating system (I did click delete to see what happens and got an error saying I need permission from trusted installer to do this, but didn't go any further). When I open task manager and look through all tasks, including 'background tasks' and 'windows processes' and can't see it anywhere

I have tried to follow the advice in this discussion:
[IIS Express Web Server Port Is In Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34898901/iis-express-web-server-port-is-in-use)

But I cannot fully understand where the solution was- I don't think I have anything called ISS installed, however there is a Local ISS when I go to 'file', 'open website', which I found through the following:
[Why and how to fix? IIS Express "The specified port is in use"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572897/why-and-how-to-fix-iis-express-the-specified-port-is-in-use)

I did as the answer marked 21 (with the green tick) suggested and restarted my computer (as one of the comments suggested) however my problem persists. There is no longer anything under 'IIS Express Sites'

I have closed all browsers then tried, restarted and then tried, still no luck
The third answer (7) I really don’t know how to do this (I don’t know what solution they are referring to), so if this is a potential solution I’d be happy for further instructions

The answer marked with a 5 about netstat -aob helped me locate a task called ‘service host: local service (network restricted) (6)’. Trying to terminate this task brings up an error saying that by terminating this task Windows will become unusable- so I assume this is why I couldn’t delete the above. The final part of this answer about elevated access I don’t know what this means or how I would do this.

Closing visual studio and restarting as an administrator doesn’t fix the problem.

I only have Edge and Internet Explorer and I have ended these via task manager whenever I have tried to resolve this problem, but it persists
I tried the answer at the bottom, but was not able to locate the folder IISExpress, maybe this is part of the problem?

Any suggestions where I might be going wrong with the above, or any further advice on how to progress some of the things above, or any new ideas will be welcome.

Comment: I had this issue before and had to change the port in the project as well as create a new virtual directory.. have you tried doing that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion Methodman. After much digging I found the solution you suggested here (change the port): [How can i change IIS Express port for a site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202885/how-can-i-change-iis-express-port-for-a-site)

The answer provided provides excellent instructions with a step by step guide on how to change the port

Just changed the port number until I got one that worked :)

Ed

Comment: Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) If you don't accept an answer, which of course you don't have to, then the Community Bot will keep bumping your question to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old post but just in case someone having the same issue recently; I tried many things including removing websites, running VS in administration mode. Nothing worked. Then I finally changed the port which finally worked. Right Click on project. Go to Web on the left menu. And change the port number at the end of the project url to whatever you want. I changed it to 50645.

Comment: Indeed, if the port is already taken by another app, changing the port will fix the issue. +1 until you find a free port is usually ok.

Comment: 50645 seems too high, make sure it doesn't overlap with `>netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp`