# ASP.Net Core Web API 'This site can't be reached'

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I just created the default 'ASP.NET Core Web API' from Visual Studio 2019, hit F5 and I have this message 'This site can't be reached'.

I tried changing the port and other solutions found online but can't make it work.
Important detail, it works on my personal computer but not my pro.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This site can't be reached error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896765/this-site-cant-be-reached-error)

Comment: Already saw this one and sadly it does not solve my issue. I don't have Web settings in this type of project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by unchecking 'Enable SSL' in the Debug settings

Answer (score 1):

FINALLY found out that this could be due to **SSL certificate error**. For me helped this (in the command line with admin privileges):

```
cd "C:\Program Files\IIS Express"
IisExpressAdminCmd.exe setupsslUrl -url:https://localhost:444 -UseSelfSigned
```

Please change the port from 444 to your port