# Failed to connect to Localhost (ASP.NET existing project)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, localhost, bitbucket

So, I have my asp.NET project (that works fine) pushed into the Bitbucket.
I cloned the project on another machine just tried to run the existing code, but the project failed to load on the web browser.

The error is-

> Can't connect to Localhost/connection refused

I tried

1. Modifying the port number under the Web tab under the option project properties
2. Tested on different browsers - IE, Edge, Chrome, and Firefox

*Note: the debugger terminates abruptly on VS*

The issue still persists.
I am sure that I am missing something here. But I have no clue about it. Please let me know if you have faced such an issue in the past/ a way to solve this issue. 
Thanks.

Comment: Note:  the debugger terminates abruptly on VS, meanwhile.

Comment: Please list the similarities and or differences between those machines in terms of `OS` , `VS version` etc 
I ask this because Also this could have nothing to do with bitbucket and would suggest you to look into this generically based on the error here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352603/localhost-refused-to-connect-error-in-visual-studio

Comment: Both machines run Windows 10 with one running VS 2015 (professional) and the other one runs VS 2017(community). I had a look at the link that you shared. but I have tried changing the port number under project properties, and that dint works either. I am guessing that there might m a problem with the IIS installation.

Comment: You need to add this information on different versions of VS to the question and search online for the same. Also update the question is which one is which - meaning what does the working one have versus the non working one

Comment: Okay, but as a matter of fact I had also tried running the same project on another machine with exact same configuration and it still gave the same error. I am wondering if it's some issue of the project itself or some IIS issue.

Comment: the debugger terminates abruptly on VS .I think your appliction is crashing as soon as it starts.Please put a breakpoint in the Application_start on global.asax and check if it hits.If it is,please start debugging from there. Otherwise ,please look at the Windows application and system event logs to check if any errors is logged from your application