# Unable to Debug or launch my MVC application in chrome

Tags: c#

I'm trying to launch my asp.net mvc sample application(c#) in chrome using visual studio but gives me the below error:

### ERROR:

This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost 49226

### ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I tried changing the port number didn't work.
Can anyone please guide me through this.

Thanks,
Akarsh

Comment: I find the same question here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352603/localhost-refused-to-connect-error-in-visual-studio )

Answer (score 0):

Re-install IIS and re-run your app:

https://www.microsoft.com/ru-RU/download/details.aspx?id=48264