# ASP.NET error "This site can’t be reached The connection was reset. "

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.net using VS 2019. I got an error when running my project. It is a simple project to show a name on the main page of the asp.net. I have tried the following steps but none of them is working out.

1. Disable my antivirus
2. My IIS range is within 44300 - 44399
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzMtS.png)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlQWk.png)
3. I have tried to delete .vs folder
   I need help<:

Comment: Click on Apply server settings and try to execute https://prnt.sc/tp24dn

Comment: Just Delete the (obj)Object folder in project folder then Run the application then It will work fine. Steps:

Right Click on the project folder then select "Open folder in file Explorer".
Then Find the Obj folder and Delete that.
Run the Application

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352603/localhost-refused-to-connect-error-in-visual-studio

Comment: @Rutuja I tried both method you mention but it's not working too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [localhost refused to connect Error in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352603/localhost-refused-to-connect-error-in-visual-studio)

Comment: @H.PauwelynI have tried most of the solution its still not working :(