# asp.net core web application got ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error in Edge in HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-core, https, microsoft-edge

I have an asp.net core web application which works in the past few months without any issue in both Edge and Chrome browser in HTTPS.

But recently found it doesn't work in Edge anymore for HTTPS, but Chrome works fine and work in HTTP for both browsers.

I have tried to reset IIS on the Azure server, remove HTTPS in the IIS binding for the site and add it back on. Neither solved the problem.

And this morning it was working for a while in Edge, but then suddenly it doesn't work again.

It seems like the application is running fine(at least in Chrome), but something to do with the Edge browser settings/security/group policy? Or am I looking at the wrong direction?

Any input would be really appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you see the _**Not secure**_ warning on the left side of the URL in the Edge browser?

Comment: @Jackdaw, No, it only shows an exclamation mark inside a circle. But if I click it, it says the connection is not secured. I just attached a screenshot with Dev tool networks tab. At the same time,  I checked Chrome, it shows secure connection.

Comment: Seems like the certificate problem. Try to check this post: [ERR_CONNECTION_RESET with SSL and ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66388671/6630084)

Comment: @Jackdaw Thanks for the link. I think I read that before. I am not sure if that could apply to my case. Mine seems like applying to everyone in the network, so I am not sure if I need to run that self sign command on each induvial users' machine?

Comment: I see, you are right. Are you using on your server certificate issued by a well-known Authority? Did you replaced the certificate on your server in the last time after your _**application worked few months without any issue**_? My be you generated the self-signed certificate the last time by your self?

Comment: @Jackdaw, yes the server certificate is generated by internal CA. This is a newly generated certificate for this application earlier this year, it's not a self signed certificate. And wired thing is the site is up and down too. I've saw others tried re-bind the certificate and waited for hours, works. First time maybe works, but only for a short period of time, I just re-bind the certificate 2nd time, so not sure how long it will last.

Comment: reinstall the edge? just like you said, in chrome it worked well, so it might relate to the browser, maybe you can try to download a firefox browser and test again.

Comment: By the way, could you pls help confirm which version of the Edge you are using now? And have you tried to upgrade to the latest version Edge?