# Running user flow: localhost refused to connect

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor application. I use Azure AD B2C for authentication. When I am trying to run a sign in user flow, I get

> This site can’t be reached

> localhost refused to connect.

Here is my launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": false,
  "anonymousAuthentication": true,
  "iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:54925",
    "sslPort": 44333
  }
},
"profiles": {
  "IIS Express": {
    "commandName": "IISExpress",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
  },
  "MyAppName": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    },
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
  }
}
}
```

This is from appsettings.json:

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
  "Instance": "https://laticreteb2c.b2clogin.com",
  "ClientId": "Set in Azure. For development, set in User Secrets (secrets.json)",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
  "Domain": "laticreteb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
  "SignOutCallbackPath": "/signout",
  "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_MyAppName_SignIn",

  "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "MyAppName_PasswordReset",
  "EditProfilePolicyId": "",
  "ClientSecret": "Set in Azure. For development, set in User Secrets (secrets.json)",
  "TenantId": "Set in Azure. For development, set in User Secrets (secrets.json)"
},
```

I am running my user flow with reply url https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc.

I know it used to work before, both locally and in production, and I cannot figure out what might break since then. How can I diagnose this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the following insights can help workaround:

This exception `This site can’t be reached   localhost refused to connect` usually occurs when there is no service listening on the IP/port you are trying to connect to Or when trying to connect to the wrong IP/port.

1. Try changing the port number
2. Or You can even try to replace the localhost with your IP address.

> And also do ensure there's no firewall blocking the connection.and whatever port you change , make sure same is given in appregistration reply url.

```
"profiles": {
        " MyAppName": {
            "commandName": "Project",
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "applicationUrl": https://localhost:44316/;http://localhost:3110 ,
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
         
        }
    }
```

Also please check if

> 1. You have started your server.
> 2. Your server is listening for connections or not.
> 3. Try deleting cookies for your localhost
> 4. Run Visual Studio as "Run as administrator"
> 5. You have Granted admin consent for open id and offline access permissions in portal.

In App settings see if instance has to be something like :

```
"Instance": https://yourb2cdomain.b2clogin.com/tfp/
```

At last if issue is still there try to find the .vs folder & Obj folder and Delete them and run again.

**References:**

1. [GitHub - JagadeshDev : Creating A Blazor Server Azure B2C App](https://github.com/JagadeshDev/BlazorAzureB2C)
2. [BlazorADB2C/BlazorADB2C at master · bdnts/BlazorADB2C · GitHub](https://github.com/bdnts/BlazorADB2C/tree/master/BlazorADB2C)
3. [Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2 · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C)

If you feel ,there is something wrong with the asp.net application configurations , you may give a try to check the issues that may cause the error here > [asp.net mvc - localhost refused to connect Error in visual studio - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352603/localhost-refused-to-connect-error-in-visual-studio?page=1&tab=modifieddesc#tab-top)