# Refused to connect to localhost when running web application as windows service

Tags: c#, web-applications, localhost, windows-services

I am trying to run a web application as a windows service. I managed to get the service to start by adding `builder.Host.UseWindowsService();` to my `Program.cs` and I also set   `builder.WebHost.UseUrls(settings.BaseUrl);`. The baseUrl is set to `"BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5011;http://*:5011"` in the settings.json file.

I published the application using `dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained --runtime win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true`. When I run the `.exe` file then the application starts up and I am able to navigate to `https://localhost:5011` successfully. But the site does not load when I try running the application as a windows service.

This is my installer.bat for starting the windows service:

```
sc create TestService binPath= %~dp0MyProgram.exe
sc failure TestService actions= restart/60000/restart/60000/""/60000 reset= 86400
sc start TestService 
sc config TestService start=auto
```

The service starts up but when I navigate to `https://localhost:5011` then I am greeted with a "This site can’t be reached. localhost refused to connect." screen.

I feel like I am missing something small that's causing this to happen. I can't seem to find any solutions online.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is about your firewall.

Check the link [https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/localhost-refused-to-connect-error#:~:text=Subscribe-,What%20Is%20the%20Localhost%20Refused%20to%20Connect%20Error%3F,Apache%20webserver%20not%20running%20properly.](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/localhost-refused-to-connect-error#:%7E:text=Subscribe-,What%20Is%20the%20Localhost%20Refused%20to%20Connect%20Error%3F,Apache%20webserver%20not%20running%20properly.)

And this [localhost refused to connect Error in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352603/localhost-refused-to-connect-error-in-visual-studio)