# trying to lunch a website application with VS2015 and port 80 is in use

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, iis-express, vs-web-site-project

I am using VS2015 and I am trying to run a website application, but every time I run the project I can't load the IISExpress because it says that the port 80 is in use, I run the Tcpview.exe from SysInternals to see who was using the port, but seems not to be in use. I found some related threads saying that can be a problem with the antivirus, I am using Symantec.

Here are the properties of the project, as you can see I tried to change the port manually, but it didn't worked

See the picture below

[image]

[image]

Comment: It appears you've not selected the start URL option. Also, can you attach the error screenshot?

Comment: Can you go to %user%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config and check if you have a bindingInformation="*:80: ?

Comment: @Gururaj I tried, actually I put that port 5001

Comment: @kblok I tried to remove that configuration as well and nothing happened

Comment: @Heinrich - This may be of little help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572897/why-and-how-to-fix-iis-express-the-specified-port-is-in-use

Comment: @Gururaj thanks, I found the answer there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is something weird, if the website is inside a solution, seems that it doesn't load correctly the application and all the time the port is ins use. I solved it using this approach

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34309702/7019416

I just loaded directly using the Visual Studio Option-> Open-> Website and removing the entries from that the post below advice