# IIS Express reports all ports already in use

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express, visual-studio-2022

When I try to run IIS Express by debugging an asp.net application in visual studio, I get an error message that the port is being used by another application, regardless of which port I select in the project properties under "Web". Why?

[image]

Comment: May be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572897/why-and-how-to-fix-iis-express-the-specified-port-is-in-use

Comment: This was first time it did not matter which port I selected, hence the new question.

Comment: Fair enough, but others coming across this question may find that info useful

Comment: If any port you chose led to the same error message, then very likely the cause is not the actual ports but your system (antivirus or some firewall). Nobody else can easily help without accessing your machine.

Comment: I made it work. I dont know how. Maybe I should just remove the question.

Answer (score 0):

Fount the same issue, changing any port was getting the same error but...

after running in a elevated CMD:

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::
```

and then

```
netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

Saw some ports being managed in the range I was "randomly selecting"

[image]

After changing to a range that was not in the managed ports, I was able to debug again.